# What is the color temperature of an iphone 8 flash?

Tags: flash, white-balance, iphone

Is it the same as the iphone 6 or is the iphone 8 stronger? Does it still use 2 LEDs?

Comment: Colour temperature is not an indication of strength/power/amount of light generated.

Comment: The Apple website says "Quad-LED True Tone flash with Slow Sync" - the page for the 6 is gone though

Answer (score 0):

iPhone 8 has 4 LEDs (2 color) while iPhone 6 got 2 leds, (2 color) therefore iPhone 8 has stronger LED.

[you can compare them there](https://www.apple.com/iphone/compare/)